# Unable to create GitHub Codestar connection to organization (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codestar

We are currently facing an issue creating a GitHub connection to AWS with the following error, despite the fact the owner of the organization is trying to create the connection:

```
You don’t have permission to create the connection. An owner with access to installation xxxxxxxxx must create the connection. If you are an organization owner, you must give the app read only access to members of the organization.
```

When we installed the AWS app, we gave it permissions to all repositories, and from the organization's applications we do see the AWS connection. Although the organization is setup to use SSO, we do not see anything under OAuth Apps inside the organization nor from the owner's personal profile.

We've tried recreating the connection several times, but cannot get away from the error message above.

Is there anything we're missing from the connection setup that is necessary for GitHub Organizations with SSO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have resolved itself over the weekend. We were able to successfully create the Codestar connection using the same steps we were using before.